# What do or what does?

Tags: verbs

Would you say:

What do a baby Range Rover and Altoids have in common ?
What does a baby Range Rover and Altoids have in common ?

Answer (score 4):

Do.  With does, it would be said "What does a baby Land Rover have in common with Altoids?"

Answer (score 1):

It can be confusing.  In "What do/does a baby Range Rover and Altoids have in common?" the subject of the composite verb "do/does have" is "a baby Range Rover and Altoids", which is plural.  Hence "do" is the correct choice.

But in "What do/does a baby Range Rover have in common with Altoids?" the subject is the singular "a baby Range Rover", so "does" is the correct choice.

And there are much more ambiguous scenarios, where it's almost a coin toss.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul Taylor that it must definitely be **'do'**. you have multiple subjects.

- What do **a baby Range Rover** (one subject) and **Altoids** (second subject) have in common ?
- What does **a baby Range Rover** (one subject) have in common with **Altoids** (second subject)?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30575/do-vs-does-with-multiple-singular-subjects
http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/what-does-or-what-do/